# My Ubuntu refuse to log In/ Boot

Tags: boot, gnome, login

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjUwF.jpg

I am an Ubuntu novice, then I decided to twerk my OS a little bit, installed on gnome display manager that ask me, if I prefer gdm3 or lightdm,and I choose gdm3, now after restarting my laptop, that is how it is since.

Update: decided to run 
Sudo apt-get remove plymouth
Now,my screen is all blank

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HhoK.jpg

Update: Someone posted an hint, that help me resolve the problem 
Alt + Ctrl + f5, then Alt + Ctrl  + f7
Thanks for the reply, the problem has now been resolved

Comment: Have you tried putting it back to lightdm?  If you can't login at all, press E on the keyboard at the GRUB screen, and add the number 1 to the end of the line that start with "linux" This will at least get you into the console.

Comment: I have been able to log in, but a lot of this have changed, most of my settings gone, I think I need to reset the OS

Comment: Hint: don't remove plymouth.

Comment: Yeah, my first mistake was removing Plymouth